# Переменная (custom variables) в Magento

Tags: cms, magento

Создал переменную. На CMS страницах выводиться без проблема, а вот в категориях и подкатегориях не хочет совершенно. Как вывести переменную в категории?

Answer (score 1):

Эти переменные созданы специально чтобы динамически добавлять данные в статические страницы, блоки и в шаблоны писем.

Чтобы работать с такими переменными где либо ещё нужно:

Допустим что у нас есть некоторый текст "бла бла {{custVar}}"

```
 $cutVar = array('custVar'  => 'текст катомной переменной');
 $text   = "бла бла {{custVar}}"

 $formater = new Varien_Filter_Template();
 $formater->setVariables($cutVar);

 var_dump($formater->filter($text));
```

Это вернет нам "бла бла текст катомной переменной"